# Locking Arrays on Constructors

Tags: multithreading, wcf, locking

I have a WCF application which receives some string arrays from client applications. Then, these arrays are passed as parameters to the constructors of some custom classes. I am not, myself, creating any threads (not even using `System.Threading`), but I would like to know if it is  bad pratice to use `lock (param.SyncRoot)` in each constructor just to play on the safe side? That's because I am making all my objects immutable, and I want to assure the arrays aren't changed in any way.

Comment: Can you show some code sample of what you do currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things.
One of the main things to keep things as easy as possible with threads is to have a clear idea of responsibilities for locking. Thus if you are not creating any threads, you do not need to lock, your locking is just making things complex, but not adding any value - a bad library will still fail.
The locking should be done inside the objects which you create and use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your object immutable you must create deep copy of the array and store that copy in the object. You also don't have to expose the array if it contains reference types. Locking array in constructor is not possible (lock is used in `using` statement - when statement ends look will end as well). Moreover locking array for whole lifetime of your object is nonsense.

Immutability itself doesn't have relation to locking. Locking is for preventing simultaneous access to your object from multiple threads - you mention you are not doing that. Immutability means that your object has state and the state cannot be changed - it is defined in the constructor and it remains the same for the whole lifetime of the object. When creating immutable objects they cannot share references with other objects and they cannot expose references to their state because that would allow modifying their state.

Comment: You didn't understand... I can, of course, use `lock (array.SyncRoot)` in the critical part of any constructor!

Comment: And what will be the purpose of doing that if you don't have multithreaded access to the array?

Answer (score 1):

How you make your objects immutable has nothing to do with your constructor or with how you pass data from one object to another.

Once the receiving object gets the array, either via the constructor or otherwise, you can pump it into a ReadOnlyCollection:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<Customer> _customers = new ReadOnlyCollection<Customer>(arrayPassedViaConstructor)
```

Now each object has its own, unmodifiable, copy of the array. Even in case the original array (in the calling object) does change, the read-only copy in the receiving objects do not.